# Sorting standards with alphanumerical data (and special characters) with case insensivity in Java

Tags: java, sorting

I have a list of characters sequences. I need to sort them in an order that feels natural. I'm coding in Java.
My initial thought was to use `Collections.sort()`. But I think this method follows the ASCII order which separates lower case and upper case text. That's not a natural flow.

Trying to define "natural sorting" I made a quick search and found the NISO TR03-1999 standard which seems to address this issue.

So I guess I need a way to sort using the algorithm defined in that standard. Is there a function in Java to do so ? Or do I need to implement it myself ?

Is there something I'm overlooking here ?

Did anyone had a similar issue in the past ? How did you deal with it ?

Here's a code sample testing Collections.sort():

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

list.add("z");
list.add("a");
list.add("Z");
list.add("A");
list.add("z 1");
list.add("a 1");
list.add("Z 1");
list.add("A 1");
list.add(" space");
list.add("!");
list.add(".");
list.add(";");
list.add("\\");
list.add("/");
list.add("+");
list.add("1");
list.add("2");
list.add("10");
list.add("1abc");
list.add("2abc");
list.add("10abc");

Collections.sort(list);

for (String string : list)
    System.out.println(string);
```

Comment: In java 8, use: Collections.sort(list, String::compareToIgnoreCase);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the Collator. Here the docs: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html

Answer (score 2):

You can make your own comparator class that compares and ignores case.

```
static class StringCompare implements Comparator<String> {               
  public int compare(String s1, String s2){
        return s1.toLowerCase().compareTo(s2.toLowerCase());
  }
}
```

And then use this to sort:

```
Collections.sort(list, new StringCompare());
```

Comment: This will solve the case sensitivity issue but won't solve other issues like accents (in languages with accents) and a bunch of other issues unless I implement a huge solution...

Comment: Also this class is totally redundant, because such a comparator already exists: [java.lang.String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER).

Answer (score 1):

Use the apache-common StringUtils in the comparator implementation:

```
class StringCompare implements Comparator<String> {               
    public int compare(String s1, String s2){
        return StringUtils.stripAccents(s1.toLowerCase()).compareTo(StringUtils.stripAccents(s2.toLowerCase()));
   }
}
```